# How php read local variable in temp function?

Tags: php, function, scope

I noticed that PHP now can use temp function definition (like js and other scripts language), but how can I get local variable in the temp function ?

ex:

```
function my_func($text, $prefix){
    $regex = '/xxxx/';
    return preg_replace_callback($regex, function($matches){
         // how to read $prefix here?
     }, $text);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Comment: Yup, but this question title is too hard to find..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `use` will do the job..

```
function my_func($text, $prefix){
    $regex = '/xxxx/';
    return preg_replace_callback($regex, function($matches) use(&$prefix){ 
                                                          //^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     }, $text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it ..

http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

```
function my_func($text, $prefix){
    $regex = '/xxxx/';
    return preg_replace_callback($regex, function($matches) use ($prefix){
         // how to read $prefix here?
     }, $text);
}
```